# Kali Linux 1.0.9 wireless not detected, even after drivers installed

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, drivers, kali-linux

I'm using Kali Linux 1.0.9 64 bits in VM.

My laptop : ASUS N76V.

Lan device : Atheros AR8161/8165 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.20) [Working]

```
ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr HIDDEN  
      inet adr:HIDDEN  Bcast:HIDDEN  Masque:HIDDEN
      adr inet6: HIDDEN Scope:Lien
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:42992 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:36241 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
      RX bytes:49935998 (47.6 MiB)  TX bytes:2996884 (2.8 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Boucle locale  
      inet adr:127.0.0.1  Masque:255.0.0.0
      adr inet6: ::1/128 Scope:Hôte
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:96 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:96 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 lg file transmission:0 
      RX bytes:5760 (5.6 KiB)  TX bytes:5760 (5.6 KiB)
```

Wlan : Intel Centrino Wireless-N 2230 [Not Working]

```
iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

The driver I need and that is installed on my computer is : iwlwifi

```
modinfo iwlwifi | grep version
version:        in-tree:
srcversion:     34D396A2F7E52E6EF4D97D7
vermagic:       3.14-kali1-amd64 SMP mod_unload modversions
```

What is the mod_unload ?

```
modinfo iwlwifi | grep firmware
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-7.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
```

I have the one I need : "firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode"

When I'm doing "lspci" I haven't the wifi card.

How can I make it functional ?

Answer (score 0):

When you run kali in vm you dont have a wireless connection, you can have wired internet though if your host gives internet to the guest which is your vm, you will have to put your network mode in vm to brided or NAT see what works for you...
And if you are going to use aircrack you wil have to get a usb adapter, I recommend a ALFA AWUSO036h which I think is the best..

Sidenote: when you run kali from the livecd you can use the wireless build into your laptop so you wont have to buy an usb then.